# How to create a custom form tag

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am planning to create a new **web application framework** like **Struts 2 and JSF**, but how to create the custom tags like **form, inputText in JSF?**

And i have an idea regarding the custom tag development, but the problem is unable to **set the request parameters, using setParameter** because such method does not exist

Already tried posting it in **JavaRanch** but no luck

please guide me

Thanks a lot in advance

Regards, 
Siddartha C.S

Comment: Modifying/setting of request parameters requires wrapping the request using [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) (basically) in a `Filter` (but that should not be needed while developing a web framework). The submitted values (request parameters) are  set in the relevant components (regarding JSF). There should not be a need to alter the request itself. Where do you find a requirement of using a method like `request#setParameter()`?

Comment: @Tiny, Thanks a lot for the quick response, actually i am not talking about JSF i am talking this in the general sense, i just want to use pure SERVLETS AND JSP, for the webapp framework, so my doubt is how to write the CUSTOM TAGS, which acts as the NORMAL HTML TAGS , but the difference is that the request should get redirected to the controller which i have chosen,